Is throwing an error in programming is good Idea at all?
I am wondering if throwing an error in programming is good Idea at all ?
While programming we throw error when something unexpected or invalid has occurred. But if we have thrown exception and it is not handled by mistake may be in programming language like node js. This will bring down whole application to halt.
Is it not better to return a result(response from any module) with error information like below
{
    error:{
        <field>:"reason of invalid"
    }
}

above indicate that request was unsuccessful, Instead of throwing error and bringing down whole system if developer has missed to apply try catch.
Please share your thought, Or help me understand when it is ideal to throw exception

Can you [edit] your question to clarify a few things? 1) What do you mean by a "response"? 2) What do you mean by "client"? Both "response" and "client" can mean different things based on the context in which they are used.

Thanks for your time, I have updated, Lets say I wrote any npm package which give result(response) with a json error, instead of throwing error on invalid request etc.

Ok, but what do you mean by "module" — these are all general terms that need more context. Can you add some example code to illustrate what you mean?

More generally, you might be interested in the exceptions versus error codes debate.

thanks Greg, I will those link, By module i mean any program, In general any library which we use

In some cases it is preferable to bring the whole system down, rather than allowing incorrect data to be generated/saved without the user's knowledge.

That is totally dependent on whether it's more important that your program doesn't terminate, or that it doesn't yield incorrect results.

@KilianFoth And what other systems might deal with the incorrect results.  I'm thinking of the first launch of the Ariane V--uncaught /0 exception resulted in a rocket breakup/firing of the flight termination system.  Had it been ignored it would have flown fine, the program that did it became moot when the rocket was lit.

When you say 'throwing errors' I think you are talking about what most people call 'exceptions'. The wisdom of exceptions is regularly debated. One of the founders of this website has an old article about his dislike of exceptions. I've seen this sentiment repeated in other contexts as well.
First, I think it's important to understand the idea behind exceptions. As the name implies, exceptions are a way to interrupt the normal flow of execution. They are 'exceptions' to that flow in the same sense that we talk about 'exceptions to the rule'. That is, an exception is stops the normal execution of the application and switches it into a different mode. A real life analogy is like triggering a fire alarm in a school. Normally students sit in class and move around the school according to their schedules, but when the fire alarm is engaged, the students are expected to not follow their normal daily routine and instead do something else entirely (i.e., leave the building.)
A good example, I think, of when they are useful is IO. When doing IO (such as reading from disk or reading from the network,) it's really important to realize that a failure can happen at any time.  Therefore, an IO read can either return some data or it could report a failure. Exceptions make this easy to distinguish.  Data is returned on the normal execution path and errors are handled on the exception path. If you don't use exceptions, you need to have some way for calling code to distinguish between receiving data without error and encountering an error. This is absolutely doable but there are many ways to solve this problem without exceptions, however, in most languages, each scenario where an error might occur can be unique. This is, IMO, one of the more valuable aspects of exceptions: they cannot be easily mistaken for normal responses. They stand out and if not handled, the application will crash. Special return codes, for example, can easily be ignored and a compilers and runtimes cannot typically determine that a program has ignored an error code.  You can, of course, squash exceptions (catch them and do nothing) but such code is easily found.
In my personal opinion, exceptions should be thrown to represent conditions that don't fit into the normal flow of an application. That doesn't mean they should always be used in that way, but I avoid using them in other cases.  In your question you write:

Instead of throwing error and bringing down whole system if developer has missed to apply try catch.

And that's precisely when exceptions are (in my opinion) a slam dunk correct approach: when you want the application to crash unless someone has specifically handled that problem. One mistake I've seen again and again is developers trying to keep a program from crashing when it is in an invalid state. To give a somewhat extreme example: should a flight computer keep running its program when its sensors are producing invalid data? I'd argue maybe/probably not. You might want it (the application, not the plane) to crash (perhaps restart) and signal to the pilot(s) to take control. Another more mundane example: if you have a program that is indexing data, should it run all night doing nothing (or corrupting data) because something is wrong? Wouldn't it be better to fail in a very clear way?
I very often write programs with no exception handling because the chance of the problem is unlikely and if it happened, it would be difficult to impossible to handle in an automated way. I prefer a crash in such scenarios.  This approach to software implementation is often referred to as fail-fast.  One of the big benefits of this approach in my experience is that you tend to find issues very quickly in testing if the application crashes and produces a stack trace which points to the exact location in code where things went sideways.

thanks for the detailed explanation, I came across node js built-In function parseInt(), which return NAN instead of throwing error, which made me think if it would have thrown error my app could have crashed,
Is this statement correct, If I say exception should be thrown based on the severity of the issue like DB connection error. And not to throw error for issues which can be handled easily.

@FaisalAhmed: Whether or not something can be handled easily is usually not a decision made by the thrower of the exception. Idiomatically, this is why throwers just throw when they reach an impasse scenario, and the consumer can either choose to catch the thrown exception (when they have a more graceful way of handling it) or not (letting the exception bubble up since they wouldn't know how to otherwise handle it). It would only crash your app if every single layer refused to catch and handle the exception, at which point the app should crash since no one knows what to do with it.

@FaisalAhmed: The flow here is: Hey, my app crashed > Oh because of this exception > [Option A] I can handle this better > Implement proper catch logic /// [Option B] I don't know how to handle this > App death is the only remaining outcome

@Flater If you watch people on their phones, they often take zero notice of an app crash. They just start it again (many apps will continue basically where you left over). What’s fatal is an app that is stuck, and the worst case that an app is stuck even after crashing and restarting.

@FaisalAhmed NaN is an interesting case.  It's true that you can avoid crashing by returning NaN but it isn't necessarily desirable.  NaN values are 'infectious' in that pretty much any mathematical operation which involves one has the result NaN.  If we go back to the airplane example, what does a control system do when it's roll, pitch, and, yaw are all reported as NaN?  Can it continue to control the plane?  Should it?

@FaisalAhmed I added a little bit to the end of the answer. You should take a look at the wikipedia page.  It elaborates on some of what is discussed here.  This article is also worth a read: https://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf

@gnasher729 I'm not talking about a mobile app though. The shortening of "app" for "application" well predates the mobile market. Secondly, the behavior of saving as you go and being able to resume is very much an intentional feature built into an application, and generally not something you see in scope of a single call stack for your average enterprise codebase.

With the talk about "NaN" being returned rather than an error being thrown - my immediate thought is that, if the NaN value being returned is not explicitly checked for and just put into another function/method/mathematical expressions, then the error is effectively masked - did the NaN happen from y/5, or was y NaN, or was 5 NaN (Presuming it was a variable)? The Exception allows us to say "No really, something went wrong, and here's when it went wrong.". Continuing from @JimmyJames' example,when the plane crashes,investigators can check the Black Box logs and see "Oh; that was NaN first.".

Its better to throw the exception because that is the built in way of returning an error response.
Say you return an error json as you suggest. Then my code has to be..
var result = library.DoThing();
//check to see if it errored
if(result.error != null) //hopefully I know it's "error" I need to check
{
   ..carry on
}
else
{
   ..do whatever you do when it errors
}

Compared to:
try
{
   var result = library.DoThing();
   DoSoemthingElse()
   DoAnotherThingThatShouldNeverGoWrong()
}
catch(e)
{
   ..do whatever you do when it errors
}


thanks Wwan for your time, I am wondering what if developer forget to add try catch block? Application will terminate its execution ? Is it a good idea, Or error should be thrown only when it is too serious like db connection error etc

If you dont catch then the exception will "bubble up" until it hits a catch or the application stops. This is a good thing, you can just put in one catch at the top level and not have to think about it again.

I came across node js built-in function parseInt, which return nan for string which can not be parsed to integer like parseInt('sad'). I think it is better way to handle exception. And to throw error only if exception is that severe that we need to stop the flow of program.

@FaisalAhmed It is awful actually because users will run into problems and developers won’t notice them and therefore not fix them.

@FaisalAhmed: The problem is, if you presume that you know every time ahead of time when an exception thrown to you is so severe that we need to stop the program is that you run into issues like the Therac-25. It can be better to err on the side of more Exceptions that can be safely handled without crashing the program that potentially crashes the program, versus having an error not be checked and do something dangerous rather than stopping the flow of the program immediately.

@FaisalAhmed It's almost always preferable to fail fast when there's an error. You might think that crashing the program is bad - but that's usually a lot better than the alternative of handling it badly, allowing the program to continue in an unstable state, corrupting data, and making it harder to figure out exactly where things started going wrong.
